# SPARQL - AND & OR Filters on Literal

Tags: filter, sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to understand how to do filtering in SPARQL with combined AND and OR conditions.

I try to find all physicists living within Newton's lifetime via the Wikidata Query Service (query.wikidata.org). This is my query:

```
SELECT ?p1 ?p1Label ?p1t1 ?p1t2 ?p2 ?p2Label ?p2t1 ?p2t2
WHERE {
  FILTER (?p1=wd:Q935) .    # Newton
  ?p1 wdt:P569 ?p1t1 .      # date of birth
  ?p1 wdt:P570 ?p1t2 .      # date of death
  ?p2 wdt:P106 wd:Q169470 . # physicist
  ?p2 wdt:P569 ?p2t1 .      # date of birth
  ?p2 wdt:P570 ?p2t2 .      # date of death
  { FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?p2t1) > xsd:dateTime(?p1t1))
  . FILTER  (xsd:dateTime(?p2t1) < xsd:dateTime(?p1t2)) }
  UNION
  { FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?p2t2) > xsd:dateTime(?p1t1))
  . FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?p2t2) < xsd:dateTime(?p1t2)) }
  UNION
  { FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?p2t1) < xsd:dateTime(?p1t1))
  . FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?p2t2) > xsd:dateTime(?p1t2)) } .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY xsd:dateTime(?p2t1)
```

The query can be processed but does not yield any results.

Each one of the three `{ FILTER . FILTER }` blocks works fine when used without the others.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can do `filter (condition1 || ... || conditionn)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If I use || instead of UNION I get errors. I tried different bracket combinations but none of them worked.

Comment: Could you provide the correct query that will be parsed by query.wikidata.org? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't suggest using || in the same page that Union is.  Replace `{... filter (test1) } Union { ... filter (test2) }` with `filter (test1 || test2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{ FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?p2t1) > xsd:dateTime(?p1t1))
  . FILTER  (xsd:dateTime(?p2t1) < xsd:dateTime(?p1t2)) }
```

evaluates to empty.

`UNION` does not "or" them together -- `||` does that.

Each branch of the `UNION` is a separate graph pattern.